# How to change current line format in QTextEdit without selection?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

there! I want to find out how to change current line format in QTextEdit?

In the document I read that

> "Formatting can be applied to the
>   current text document using the
>   setCharFormat(), mergeCharFormat(),
>   setBlockFormat() and
>   mergeBlockFormat() functions. If the
>   cursor has no selection, current block
>   format will be changed."

But in my application, the current block in which cursor is couldn't be changed. May I miss something? Then how could I change current block format which has no selection?

Here is my code:

```
QTextCursor cursor = this->textCursor();
QTextBlockFormat blockFmt;
blockFmt.setNonBreakableLines(true);
blockFmt.setPageBreakPolicy(QTextFormat::PageBreak_AlwaysBefore);
QTextCharFormat charFmt;
charFmt.setFont(data->visualFont());
if(!cursor.hasSelection()) {
    cursor.beginEditBlock();
    cursor.setBlockFormat(blockFmt);
    cursor.mergeBlockCharFormat(charFmt);
    QTextBlock block = cursor.block();
    block.setUserData(data);
    cursor.endEditBlock();
}
```

What I want to do is: change current line's format if there is no selection. So if cursor.hasSelection() is false, I just merge new format to block chars. But this does not work.

I also tried add setTextCorsor(cursor); after cursor.endEditBlock();, but it still doesn't work. In fact, after adding this, the whole block becomes invisible.

So how could I change current block format which has no selection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pls, check if an example below would work for you, it should change the current text block format and font.

```
QTextCursor cursor(myTextEdit->textCursor());

// change block format (will set the yellow background)
QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = cursor.blockFormat();
blockFormat.setBackground(QColor("yellow"));
blockFormat.setNonBreakableLines(true);
blockFormat.setPageBreakPolicy(QTextFormat::PageBreak_AlwaysBefore);
cursor.setBlockFormat(blockFormat);

// change font for current block's fragments
for (QTextBlock::iterator it = cursor.block().begin(); !(it.atEnd()); ++it)
{
    QTextCharFormat charFormat = it.fragment().charFormat();
    charFormat.setFont(QFont("Times", 15, QFont::Bold));

    QTextCursor tempCursor = cursor;
    tempCursor.setPosition(it.fragment().position());
    tempCursor.setPosition(it.fragment().position() + it.fragment().length(), QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
    tempCursor.setCharFormat(charFormat);
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: also you might want to take a look at the QSyntaxHighlighter class (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) could be helpful for what you're trying to do